# How to save many story in assert in android

Tags: android, android-assets

I am creating an application where data are saved in .txt file in assets folder, I am trying to retrieve my data but I am not able to do, My teacher conditions to not to use SQLite and shared preference.

Comment: you can copy the string to string.xml and create a string-array in string.xml. Fetch the story list from the array and display in listview. For showing the story fetch each story from string.xml

Comment: I have use create string in value but i want to save in assert. Have another  way ?

Answer (score 0):

Place your text file in the /assets directory under the Android project. Use AssetManager class to access it.

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");
```

Or you can also put the file in the /res/raw directory, where the file will be indexed and is accessible by an id in the R file:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```